# Trying to paint after pressing a button

Tags: java, button, applet, actionlistener, paint

How can i make it repaint after pressing the button? When i start the applet up it paints 2 rects at random positions with random widths and heights, how can i get them to "respawn" at a different  location after pressing the button?

```
package test;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Applet implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    boolean running = true;
    Random r = new Random();
    public int randX = r.nextInt(400);
    public int randY = r.nextInt(400);
    public int randW = r.nextInt(100);
    public int randH = r.nextInt(100);

    public int randX2 = r.nextInt(400);
    public int randY2= r.nextInt(400);
    public int randW2 = r.nextInt(100);
    public int randH2 = r.nextInt(100);


    public void start(){thread.start();}
    public void stop(){}
    public void init(){
        setSize(500,500);
        Button randomButton = new Button("RANDOMNESS");
        randomButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(randomButton);
    }

    public void run(){}
    public void destroy(){}

    public void paint(Graphics g){ //paints rect with random with and height
        g.fillRect(randX, randY, randW, randH);
        g.fillRect(randX2, randY2, randW2, randH2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// How can they repaint at a different random location after pressing the button?
        System.out.println("WORKING");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you simply change randX, randY,.... within your `actionPerformed(...)` method by giving them new random values, just as you're currently doing, and then call `repaint()` to signal the applet to repaint itself?

---

Just as an aside, what is this code supposed to be doing?

```
Thread thread = new Thread();

// .....

public void start(){thread.start();}
```

Per my view, it's not doing much.

Comment: Oh that is just for later, thought i would already implement it, but you are right, its not doing much right now